# Does an induced magnetic field in a conductor change the existing current in the conductor?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

So a conductor placed in a changing magnetic field induces a current in the conductor. This current induces a new magnetic field counter-acting the existing magnetic field.

This will change the overall magnetic field. Does this then induce a new current and a new induced magnetic field in an infinite loop?

Or does the conductor only "respond" to changes in the external magnetic field, and not its own induced magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the magnetic field induced by the current in the conductor will induce a current on the conductor. The magnetic flux of that field and the current are proportional and the constant of proportionality $L$ is called autoinductance or just inductance.
$$ \Phi_{\text{M}} = L I $$

That's why when studying a circuit of variable current one should add the inductance of the circuit itself (Kirchoff Law doesn't holds in that case). Most of the time I believe it's approximated to $L=0$.

From Faraday's Law,
$$\mathcal{E} = -\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\text{M}}$$
where $\Phi_{\text{M}} = \Phi_{\text{current}} + \Phi_{\text{ext}}$ is the total flux. The flux due to the current is written, by definition, as $\Phi_{\text{current}} = LI$.

Comment: How would this work if you wanted to find EMF? I know EMF equals the rate of change in magnetic flux. I have always assumed you can just use the rate of change of the external magnetic field. But really, you have to add the contribution from the induced magnetic field?

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer your comment. I had also corrected the second sentence where ''they'' should be refering to the flux and the current, not the field and the current. Now it should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If the conductor is in the shape of a coil, the self-inductance can be significant.  At any instant, the current is in equilibrium, determined in part by the rest of the circuit.